# MVC razor return confirm variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have written this small piece of razor code with java script:

```
@Html.ActionLink("ערוך", "Edit", new { id = item.tz }) |
@Html.ActionLink("הצג פרטים מלאים", "Details", new { tz = item.tz }) |
@{
var shem = ("האם אתה בטוח שברצונך למחוק את" + @Html.ValueFor(model => item.fname) + " " + @Html.ValueFor(model => item.lname) + "?");
@Html.ActionLink("מחק", "Delete", new { id = item.tz }, htmlAttributes: new { onclick = "return confirm('shem');"} )
}
```

All I want is for the variable to be displayed in the "return confirm," but for some reason it doesn't recognize that as a variable and will only write it down literally.

Things I've tried so far:

1. Putting the while variable in the "return confirm" and avoid using a variable completely.
2. Putting the name of the variable with an @ in front of it.
3. removing the whole thing from the @{} (which caused the whole variable line to be rendered as a

   in the HTML page).
4. Removing the '' around the variable's name in the "return confirm."

So what am I doing wrong? I'm sure it'll end up being a small syntax thing, but I just can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
onclick = "return confirm(" + Json.Encode(shem) + ");"
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm!
Can you please explain to the students among us the idea behind this solution?
Am I understanding correctly that you didn't open and close the brackets, but instead closed the brackets for the "return confirm," inserted the variable, and then opened new brackets for the remainder of the java code?

Comment: `onclick` is a string in C#. This string is formed by concatenating 3 strings. The first is `return confirm(`, the second is `Json.Encode(shem)` and the third is `);`. The `Json.Encode` function will in turn add double quotes around the resulting value, so you will end up with the correct javascript statement: `return confirm("xxxxx");`